# Vraptor: conflito de rotas

Tags: java-ee, vraptor

Estou desenvolvendo uma sistema de notícias pra um cliente, e estou passando por uma dificuldade, no momento que irei gravar a notícia no banco, surge a seguinte mensagem:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are two rules that matches the uri '/noticias/persistir' with method POST: [FixedMethodStrategy: /noticias/{listaUltimasNoticias} mais [POST]], [FixedMethodStrategy: /noticias/persistir persistir [POST]] with same priority. Consider using @Path priority attribute.

No meu controller o método de persistir esta assim:

NoticiasController.java

```
@Post("/noticias/persistir")
public void persistir(Noticia noticia){
     [...]
}
```

E meu formulario de edição ou inserção de notícia está assim:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/noticias/persistir'/>" method="post"
            class="form-horizontal" role="form">

      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                name="noticia.tipo" value="Noticia"/> 
//corpo do formulário tudo correto

</form>
```

Esse formulário se inserção e edição já funcionou, porém começou a apontar esse erro, o que pode ser? E como corrijo?

Comment: Considerou usar na  controller `@Path("/noticias/persistir")`??

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino considerei e tentei fazer porém o msm erro ocorre

Comment: Você criou alguma outra rota com esse mesmo parâmetro `@Post("/noticias/persistir")` se criou tente passar um id tipo `{noticias.id}/persisitr`

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino eu nao criei outra rota com esse parametro, como eu disse, antes tava rodando certo, agora comecou a aparecer esse erro ae, sem que eu alterasse o controller e nem o formulario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tudo bem? O próprio erro já te dá uma boa dica. As duas rotas a seguir conflitam:

`/noticias/{listaUltimasNoticias} e noticias/persisti`

o problema é que a primeira recebe uma variável como parâmetro, e como é uma variável, `{listaUltimasNoticias}` pode ser qualquer coisa, incluindo `persisti` que é o sufixo do segundo path. Algumas alternativas para resolver são:

1) mudar alguma das duas rotas, claro

2) definir prioridade no seu path. Por exemplo:

`@Post @Path(value='/noticias/persisti', priority=HIGHEST)
public void seuMetodo() {...}`

Você encontra uma explicação completa, com um exemplo em:
http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/controllers-rest/#definindo-prioridades-para-seus-paths

Comment: hehe, nada como um dos commiters respondendo!